# clustalw installation on Mac

Tags: macos, dmg

I am really confused on how to install clustalw2.

I downloaded a macosx.dmg file and when I double clicked on it I saw a folder and inside it two icons, one was a help page (I did read that but its on use of clustalw not installation)

When I clicked the other icon it open a terminal that I can use to align but thats not what I want to do....I want to use the following command in a piece of code

from Bio import Clustalw

I am not sure how to go about this.

I tried clustalx (the GUI version) and again it executes it and gives me a window to select a file to align but again no installation in the python path.

(I tried using the tag "clustalw but I cannot use it since its never been used and I am not high up to start new tags, in case someone wonders why I have not used it)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I could use

FINK to install clustalW

I thought I will share this in case someone else needs it too.